# cannot convert 'int' to 'node *'

Tags: postfix-notation, turbo-c++, infix-operator

i am reading a c++ source code,
converting infix to postfix
i am using turbo c++

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 typedef struct node
{
  float data;
  struct node *next;
} stack;

void StackInitiate(stack **head)
{
  //error
  if(*head=(stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack))==NULL)
      exit(1);
  (*head)->next=NULL;
}
```

// I'm getting .. cannot convert 'int' to 'node *' ...

can anybody tell me why so . and how to solve it regards.

full source code [here](http://dr-bios.com/infix_to_postfix.zip)

Comment: Turbo C++ -- did I just time travel to the 90s?

Comment: I hope they don't make you use Turbo C++ in your place of study and you're just confused...

Comment: Turbo C++ is only tangentially related to the C++ language as we know it today. I have added the "turboc++" tag and I would recommend removing the C++ tag as well.

Comment: a good practice. Kindly don't use turbo c. Use codeblocks or dev c++.

Comment: thanks,from now I will not use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the expression

```
*head=(stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack))==NULL
```

is actually equivalent to

```
*head=((stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack))==NULL)
```

That is, you assign the value of the comparison to `*head`.

You need to put in your own parentheses to make it correct:

```
(*head=(stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack)))==NULL
```

Or better yet use the `new` operator which is what you rreally should use to allocate object dynamically in C++:

```
(*head=new stack)==NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of operator precedence rules, the following:

```
if(*head=(stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack))==NULL)
```

is parsed as

```
if(*head=((stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack))==NULL))
```

which is assigning the result of the `== NULL` comparison to `*head`.

To compare the new value of `*head` to null instead, use parentheses to change the precedence:

```
if((*head=(stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack)))==NULL)
```

Or even better, separate the assignment from the if condition:

```
*head = (stack *) malloc(sizeof(stack));
if(*head == NULL)
```

This convention is more readable and would also avoid similar bugs happening in the future.